# nodejs how to retrieve variable value from mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have a piece of code where I want to get the value of a variable from mysql database.

```
var PNOP;

  connection.query('SELECT pnop FROM MASTER1', [PNOP], function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
 });
```

The connection query is working fine but the var PNOP is not getting updated.

The log file is showing the following entry:

`[ { pnop: 7915.2 } ]`

The value that I need to set as PNOP is 7915.2 which is what is in the mysql database.

What should I do to get the variable value?

Answer (score 2):

The way nodejs-mysql works, the second parameter for the query contains the values of the fields you want to escape, and not the output parameters.
The result of the query is in "results", as your log shows. what your code should be is:

```
var PNOP;

connection.query('SELECT pnop FROM MASTER1', [], function(err, results) {
  PNOP = results[0].pnop;
 });
```

Comment: The results[0].pnop is giving the correct value - when i log it.  However, the var PNOP value does not seem to be getting set with this value.

Comment: When i log the value of PNOP it says undefined.

Comment: Yes - i tried it as it is - the var value was not getting set. so i added a line

Comment: console.log(results[0].pnop) - and in the log it was getting recorded as 7915.20